# PHP, ajax, xml, jQuery - Dynamic search only returns one value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to implement a dynamic search function in html, jQuery, ajax and php.
The problem is that the search function only does the search when you have entered 2-3 letters.
E.g: When pressing letter "f" it should return every row in database which contains the letter "f". The return **data** is empty.(It should return 20 values, i've tested the query)
Right now it only returns a result when writing "foo", maybe it's because the that is the only row which have the name. This time it returns the xml structure:

```
<picture>
   <picuser>CorrcetUser</picuser>
   <picurl>CorrectURL</picurl> 
   <pictime>CorrectTime</pictime>
   <picid>CorrectID</picid>
   <comment>
        <commenttime>Foo</commenttime>
        <commentuser>Foo</commentuser>
        <commenttext>Foo</commenttext>
   </comment>
   <description>
         Foo bar
   </description>  
</picture>
```

Here is the code right now:

the javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".search").keyup(function() {
      var searchbox = $(this).val(); // get the string in the searchbox
      var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchbox;
      if (searchbox == '') {

      } else {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "search.php",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : "xml",
            async: false,
            cache : false,
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                //Data repsonse from server
                                console.log(data);  
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
         
            }
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Here is the search.php

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.inc.php');

if ($_POST) {
echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>';


$searchword = $_POST['searchword'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM picture WHERE description LIKE :searchword";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute(array('searchword' => '%' . $searchword . '%'));
$nr=0;
$outputXML ="";
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row) {

    $outputUser =  $row['userName'];
    $outputPicURL = $row['picURL'];
    $outputTime = date('Y-m-d H:i',  $row['time']); 
    $outputString = $row['description'];    
    $outputPicID = $row['pictureID'];   

    $outputXML.= "<picture>
                <picuser>$outputUser</picuser>
                <picurl>$outputPicURL</picurl> 
                <pictime>$outputTime</pictime>
                <picid>$outputPicID</picid>
                <comment>
                    <commenttime>Foo</commenttime>
                    <commentuser>Foo</commentuser>
                    <commenttext>Bar</commenttext>
                </comment>
            <description>
                Foo bar
            </description>  
        </picture>";

 }
 echo $outputXML;
}


?>
```

I thought this was an easy fix, but here I'm stuck.
And wondering why **data** is empty?

Comment: `async: false,` why??

Comment: I thought that was good practice when fetching from a database, is it a bad idea? It works either way.

Comment: Is this for an intranet or internet site? This is probably a bad idea, because this is a DOS attack waiting to happen.  Imagine a user comes to the site and begins triggering the keyup event of your search box over and over again sending a multitude of requests to your server. Then imagine multiple users do the same thing.  If they are using standard browsers(chrome,IE,firefox,etc.) than there is a limit to the number of requests that can be made, but if they are using a custom browser designed for such attacks you're giving a really easy way to bring your server down via a DOS attack

Comment: This is for a school project that i run locally on MAMP. I have not really thought about the security aspect. However, I'm glad you pointed that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml documents need a single root element. You need to output it:

```
if ($_POST) {
   header('Content-type: application/xml');
   echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>';
   echo '<pictures>';
   ...
   foreach($results as $row) {
     $outputUser = htmlspecialchars($row['userName']);
     ...
   }
   echo '</pictures>';
}
```

Some Browsers (like IE) will only parse the response into a DOM if an XML content type is provided (`header('Content-type: application/xml');`).

If you output values in xml using string function (like `echo`) you need to escape the values (`htmlspecialchars()`). Otherwise characters like `<` or `&` can break your xml.

Last, if you get XML as a string in Javascript, you can create a `DOMParser` and use it to parse it.